# ::before syntax with a :hover effect

Tags: html, css, sass

I have this question. Here in this part:

```
&__item::before {
    // Style...
}

&__item:hover::before, 
&__item--active::before { 
    transform: scaleY(1); 
    width: 100%; 
}
```

The ***::before*** actually knows that the style that he has to apply is to the **''before item''** when hovered?
I ask this because I created one effect all whole with the before pseudo-element, and this syntax seems to look like ***''When the item is hovered, create a pseudo-element with that style"***

Comment: are you asking about the use of ::before selector with ::hover?

Comment: I'm asking about how does the ::before knows that the actually needs to apply that style to the item::before that's above him

Comment: When I hover, that `:hover::before` will know that it's the `before` above him? Meaning that's just one `item::before` I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the question, but if you want to properly select the selectors pseudo, just make sure that the nesting is right.

Smth like this:

```
  &__item {
    // Selector
    &:before {
      // Selector pseudo (:before)
    }

    &--active,
    &:hover {
    // Hover||Active applied on Selector
      &:before {
        // Hover||Active applied on Selector pseudo (:before)
      }
    }
  }
```

Please check this pen: https://codepen.io/edonrexhepi/pen/qBdvVXe?editors=1100

Comment: Yeah, that was the answer I was looking for, thanks!